# How to properly detect hidden iframes?

Tags: html, dom, iframe

I have html of all the iframes embedded in the page. I want an accurate method to detect which iframes were invisible. The invisibility can be achieved by placing a transparent image, or making iframe size zero or making seamless="seamless", or using "invisible" attribute value. Is there a tool or method that we can use to quickly identify number of iframes invisible to human eye. 
thanks

Answer (score 2):

Get the iframe's [bounding rectangle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getBoundingClientRect), compute its area and whether. If the area is greater than zero then probe each corner with [document.elementFromPoint()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.elementFromPoint). If none of the corners resolves to the element then it's probably invisible. This checks whether it's hidden beneath other elements or possibly outside the overflow box of its parent containers.

You also need to check whether any of its corners has positive coordinates, since browsers don't let you scroll to negative offsets.

Do note that this method is not perfect, there are some edge-cases it may not cover, e.g. a transparent `<div>` with `pointer-events: none;` laid over the iframe has practically no effect and thus the iframe might as well be considered visible.

> The invisibility can be achieved [...] making seamless="seamless"

That doesn't make an iframe invisible

Comment: right. making seamless dosent make iframe invisible.. I have another question, if the bounding area is negative, what does this means {'y': -10000, 'x': 0},{'width': 300, 'height': 150}.

Comment: that's offset + dimensions, the area isn't negative. although this would mean that the iframe is outside the reachable viewport. which indeed is another thing to consider